# How to bind a SQL statement with multiple IN values?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i am trying to fire query with multiple IN values but binding params in sqlite open helper rawQuery()

Static query

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE inIdUser IN (2,4,5)
```

but want to do it like

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE inIdUser IN (?)";
Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, new String[]{"2,4,5"};
```

it don't show result and nothing error appers
but if i pass only one value like

```
Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, new String[]{"2"});
```

then works

Comment: Would the `WHERE IN` clause always have exactly three values in it?

Comment: no sir its just example, it would have different values

Comment: Does the `inIdUser` column contain _single_ numerical values, or does it contain CSV?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE inIdUser IN (?,?,?)` and then bind each parameter to a number.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `rawQuery()` the result will be this:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE inIdUser IN ('2,4,5')
```

because the placeholder will be replaced by the string literal `"2,4,5"` wrapped between single quotes.
This is why this does not work.
 
 
What you can do is use the operator `LIKE` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || inIdUser || ',%'
```

which after the replacement of the placeholder will be:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE ',' || '2,4,5' || ',' LIKE '%,' || inIdUser || ',%'
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE ',2,4,5,' LIKE '%,' || inIdUser || ',%'
```

So write your code like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || inIdUser || ',%'";
Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, new String[]{"2,4,5"});
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the `inIdUser` column contains _individual_ ID values, not CSV, so your answer is in the wrong direction.

Comment: What I understand by the query: `SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE inIdUser IN (2,4,5)` is that `inIdUser` is a column of the table.

Comment: If it's the case that you describe how would this work: `Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, new String[]{"2"});` as the OP says at the end.

Comment: It seems to work because the raw query becomes `WHERE inIdUser IN ('2')`.  In any case, many prepared statement frameworks can't handle `WHERE IN` with an arbitary number of parameters.

Comment: If `inIdUser` is not a column in the table but a variable, the statement would not compile as it is. The variable should be replaced with its actual value, by concatenation or a placeholder. Nothing like that is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's no way of doing that **(2,4,5)** into a single value . A string of the form **"?, ?, ..., ?"** can be  dynamically created and safely put into the original SQL query

```
String[] ids = { 2, 4, 5 }; // set ids
String query = "SELECT * FROM invoices"
    + " WHERE inIdUser IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.length, "?"))  + ")";
Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, ids);
```

Comment: thanks buddy, not i understand thats final solution

Comment: TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.length, "?")) will create (?,?,?) for you. "?" will be dynamic according to "ids.length"